# Do I have to pay for a drink if a vendor cannot accept payment?

Tags: united-kingdom, commerce, restaurants, legal-tender

Recently I was served a drink at the pub where I intended to pay by debit card and had no alternative payment method available (e.g. cash).

The card reader was faulty and I consumed my drink whilst the barman was attempting to fix the reader. Consumption of the drink before payment was with the barman's consent.

In the end, the card reader was fixed, but **if the vendor cannot accept payment for a non-returnable product and the consumer intended to pay, then is the payment waived and the product free?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In general, you still need to pay for the drink.

If you had purchased the drink (on credit, ie a tab or similar as you appear to have done), and you had offered the vendor CASH, and he had refused, [if you can prove you offered him cash] he would be unable to pursue you for the  debt (technically you would still owe it to him, but as he had declined government issued tender the government won't act on his claim, so he has no remedy available to him to extract payment - although he can refuse to serve you in future etc).

Paying through a debit card is not the same as paying cash - although the money goes out of your account and into his, its not "legal tender" in the same way cash is.

Comment: Regarding your statement about offering cash, this is a common misconception about U.S. currency. A business is free to e.g. not accept large bills or require payment via check or money order. Is this different in the U.K.? ("[There is, however, no Federal statute mandating that a private business, a person or an organization must accept currency or coins as for payment for goods and/or services](https://www.treasury.gov/resource-center/faqs/Currency/Pages/legal-tender.aspx)")

Comment: The situation may be different in the USA and UK.    See http://www.royalmint.com/aboutus/policies-and-guidelines/legal-tender-guidelines (second statement).

Comment: @Turch: The US business is free not to enter a contract with you in the first place. So if you try to buy a sandwich with a $100 note, the cashier can say "No", and no contract is created. Same in the UK. In addition, large amounts of coins are not legal tender (more than 20p in pennies I think, for example).

Comment: @gnasher729 what if you already ate the sandwich? What if there were a sign saying "no $100s"? What if there were no such sign?

Comment: @phoog Then you post another question :-)

Comment: @gnasher729 hmm, I can almost hear the reputation accruing already.